# Quotes problem when passing value to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am using like

```
$myPage .= '<td><a href=\'javascript:editProduct('
    .$row['id']
    .',"'
    .$row['name']
    .'")\'>Edit</a></td>';
```

where `$row['name']` has quotes in its value. it breaks. how do i solve the issue both from php side and js side...

`$row['name']` is value from DB. and it will have value like `pradeep's` and `pradeep"s` also

i used like

```
$myPage .= '<td><a href=\'javascript:editProduct('.addslashes($row['id']).',"'.addslashes($row['name']).'")\'>Edit</a></td>';
```

it solves the issue of double quotes. but when i have single quotes in value the javascrit link looks like

```
javascript:editProduct(28,"pradeep\
```

it actually breaks..

And how do i strip down the slashes added by addslashes in javascript..

UPDATE - FINAL CODE

```
$myPage .= '<td><a href=\'javascript:editProduct('.$row['id'].',"'.htmlentities($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES).'")\'>Edit</a></td>';
```

and js looks like

```
function editProduct(id,name){
        alert(name);
        }
```

can any one solve my issues

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, but it seems you have to scape quotes on `$row['name']` before using it.

Comment: Don't forget that single and double quotes aren't the only problem characters for this type of code, you also need to escape backslashes, carriage-returns, new-lines, line-feeds, maybe tab characters...(depending on your data, of course: you may be sure that some of those characters won't ever occur)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$myPage .= "<td><a href='javascript:editProduct({$row['id']},\""
           . htmlentities( $row['name'] )
           . "\")'>Edit</a></td>";
```

`htmlentities` default behaviour is to convert double quotes and leave single quotes alone, if you require converting single *and* double quotes, then call it like this:

```
htmlentities( $row[ 'name' ], ENT_QUOTES )
```

Also, using `{ .. }` in `"..."` strings is the correct way to substitute variables.

Comment: @Oerd - i guess u did not get my question properly. please see my question again.

Comment: @pradeep you're right, I was too quick on the trigger, then I guess your choice is wrapping `$row['name']` in a call to `htmlentities`.

Comment: @Oerd - but when i have value like pradeep"s the function is becoming like javascript:editProduct(28,"pradeep"s") which is breaking the function.its not escaping the double quotes

Comment: @pradeep `htmlentities( 'pradeep"s' )` will output `pradeep&quot;s`

Comment: @Oerd - i get error like           Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File: javascript:editProduct(29,"p"s")
Line: 1, Column: 18
Source Code:
editProduct(29,"p"s")

Comment: @pradeep, are you sure you **are using** `htmlentities`??? Look at my answer again.

Comment: @Oerd - i have added that. then also i am getting that error.

Comment: @pradeep, I'll have time to check your code locally later on. sorry for the delay, but gotta earn my daily bread over here :)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP string

```
'<a href=\'javascript:editProduct('.$row['id'].',"'.$row['name'].'")\'>';
```

outputs (assuming some values)

```
<td><a href='javascript:editProduct(123,"abc")'></td>
```

Presumably it breaks if $row['name'] contains a " quote. You could replace such quotes with a \" in the string before you output it using `str_replace('"', '\"', $row['name'])`

Comment: y cant i use addslashes instead of str_replace("'", "\'", $row['name']) u have used

Comment: @pradeep addslashes works too. I don't like it because I stay clear of anything to do with magic quotes, but it's fine.